# Issue getting device targeting information google ads api

Tags: c#, google-ads-api

I want to get Device Targeting Information from Google Ads Api as show in below screen shot:

[image]

Currently from what i get from the documentation i am doing this :

```
string  query = $@"SELECT campaign_criterion.device.type FROM campaign_criterion";
      // also tried this query 
query = $@"SELECT campaign.id, campaign_criterion.device. FROM Device WHERE campaign.id =           {campaignId}";
      
    PagedEnumerable<SearchGoogleAdsResponse, GoogleAdsRow> result =
              googleAdsService.Search(customerId.ToString(), query);

           foreach (GoogleAdsRow criterionRow in result)
            {
                DeviceInfo device = criterionRow.CampaignCriterion.Device;
            }
```

I have randomly tried many other but i always see NULL in Device i have been able to successfully get Keywords , Ad Schedule View and works fine but cannot seem to get this working any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i needed :

```
   query =
           @"SELECT campaign.name, campaign.status, segments.device,
                metrics.impressions, metrics.clicks, metrics.ctr,
                metrics.average_cpc, metrics.cost_micros
        FROM campaign WHERE segments.date = '2020-11-11'";
```